# What dug this hole under my compost heap?

Tags: identification, compost, wildlife

This morning we noticed something has dug a large hole (20-30cm wide) under our compost heap. I'm not sure if they were digging out of our garden or into it. Based on my research I think it is either a badger sett or fox den based on its size. We live next to a small wooded area (about 100m away from the edge), so I think both badgers and foxes likely live near us. Is there anything I can do to distinguish between these?

Extra information: We are in Cheshire in the UK, and there is a large pile of dirt surrounding the entrance to the hole. It is directly underneath our compost bin.
[image]

Comment: You can get a trail camera pretty cheap these days, it will capture photos when it senses movement and you will know for sure which animal citizen has fallen in love with your warm compost pile.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're lucky enough to spot the occupant during the day, it's a case of keeping a watch at night, especially if it's a badger, since they rarely appear in daylight, though foxes might.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some chalk dust to see if you can get a clear footprint.

Around here my first suspect would be groundhogs/aka woodchucks.  I'm not familiar with the creatures of the UK.